# If statement with multiple conditions in Swift

Tags: swift

I have an if statement where I would like to have two conditions like the following :

```
if let name = json["resource"]["fields"]["name"].stringValue && name.hasPrefix("/")
```

When I do that, I got an error "Use of unresolved identifier name".
What's the solution then?

```
if let name = json["resource"]["fields"]["name"].stringValue && "test".hasPrefix("/"){
```

If I do this instead, I got an error "Optional type '$T16' cannot be used as a boolean; test for '!= nil' instead"

It's probably a stupid question but I must confess I'm lost...

Thanks for your help

Comment: maybe `let name = json["resource"]["fields"]["name"].stringValue if name != nil && name.hasPrefix("/"){`

Comment: Yeah I've done the 'if let name = json["resource"]["fields"]["name"].stringValue {
 if name.hasPrefix("/") {' but I thought there was a way to avoid to do 2 if statement and put the 2 conditions into only one if statement

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You aren't using a regular if statement, you're using optional binding, and you can't combine the binding with a check on the bound value like that. You could break it up to something like this though.

```
if let name = json["resource"]["fields"]["name"].stringValue {
    if name.hasPrefix("/") {
        // stuff
    }
}
```

**Edit**: Looks like this has changed in [Swift 1.2](http://adcdownload.apple.com//Developer_Tools/Xcode_6.3_beta/Xcode_6.3_beta_Release_Notes.pdf). According to the release notes, it's now possible to add extra conditions to the if let, while let statements:

> The “if let” construct has been expanded to allow testing multiple
>   optionals and guarding conditions in a single if (or while) statement
>   using syntax similar to generic constraints:

```
if let name = json["resource"]["fields"]["name"].stringValue where name.hasPrefix("/") {
    // stuff
}
```

The code above should achieve what you want. (Untested)

Comment: Thanks. That's what I've done in the end. Didn't actually realise I couldn't combine the optional binding with another check.

Comment: @Nico It looks like you asked this question a few hours too early :). Check out the edit. It's untested because I'm still waiting for the new beta to download. I'll update this later if it turns out that my syntax is a little off.

Comment: Yay! One less level of nesting for my conditionals :)